Customize the dot marker with tooltip on line chart (ApexCharts)
I'm trying to create a custom library of chart component with Apexcharts and Vue3Apexcharts. I would like to be able to customize this little dot (marker)
Here is what I would like to customize
I tried looking through the doc, online, can't find anything. Also checked if it was SVG generated or added through HTML and it seems to be directly made with SVG, so I don't really know how to handle this.

this documentation page seems relevant.

they're talking about the dot on the tooltip not markers on the chart in general
